# Loading a simple sprite from a sprite-sheet

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I know that when you load a sprite frame with :

```
  CCSprite *temp=[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"can%i.png",rand]];
```

it usually takes the sprite from the last sprite-sheet in the cache .

I want to load a specific sprite from a specific sprite sheet :

load `sprite1.png` from `spritesheet1.png` .
How would i do that ?

Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by ensuring you have only unique sprite frame names, or by ensuring you properly load/unload atlases containing duplicate frames but this is difficult since any texture in use will keep the texture in memory